# How to fractionate a 2^4 x 3 factorial with a nominal categorical

Tags: experiment-design, fractional-factorial

I've only just been taking a dive into DoE, so I'm still green on how to setup the designs according my experiment, so this question is more about confirming my understanding of experimental design.

I'm designing an experiment with four two-level factors, one of which an ordinal categorical, and one nominal categorical three level factor, so $2^4 \cdot 3$. I'm only really interested in the main effects of the two level factors on the nominal categorical three-level factor. I am not necessarily limited in the amount of runs or time, but I would like to reduce it to a manageable amount as each run takes at least a day, and I would like to understand exactly why a couple of designs would be appropriate or why not.

Am I correct in understanding that for an OA (i.e. $L.12.2^4.3^1$) the full design space will not be covered for each of the nominal categorical levels, because the 3-level categorical is treated as quantitative? In which case, is it okay in this case to say that a $2^{4-1}*3$ design is more appropriate to probe the effects of the two-level factors on the three-level factor?